# How do I extract the user's email from a comment on a post in a rails forum app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

I need to be able to display the email of the user who commented on a post in my rails app.

I've already made sure that all of my associations are correct and inside of the create method I logged the `current_user.email` and the `@comment.user.email` which both return the correct values. However, in the `_comment` partial, I keep getting an error that the user is nil.

The models:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  validates :comment_text, presence: true
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

The controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    @comments = Comment.all.order('created_at ASC')
end

def show
end

def new
    @comment = Comment.new
end

def create
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.user.email = current_user.email
    puts current_user.email
    puts @comment.user.email


    if @comment.save
        flash[:success] = 'Your comment has been added to the post'
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Something went wrong. Your comment was not added to the post'
        render 'new'
    end
end

def update
end

def edit
end

def destroy
end

private

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:comment_text, :post)
end

def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
end
end
```

The partial view:

```
<p><%= comment.comment_text %></p>
<p><%= comment.user %></p>
<p><%= comment.user_id %></p>
<p><%= comment.user.email %>
```

The post show view:

```
<div class="comment-div">
    <%= render @post.comments %>
</div>
```

I'm expecting to see the commenter's email, but instead, I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #4):
2
3
4

<p><%= comment.user %></p>
<p><%= comment.user_id %></p>
<p><%= comment.user.email %>
```

Comment: That error is telling you the `user` or `comment` is `nil`.  The code you have should display the user's email just fine, once all the values are there.  Are you passing the `comment` value to the partial correctly?

Comment: I think you only need to link your `comment` to the current user like `@comment.user = current_user`, or `@comment.user_id = current_user.id`. your `current_user` already has an email, you don't have to assign it again. In the end `@comments.user` and `current_user` are the same record in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Starting rails 5, all `belongs_to` associations are mandatory unless stated otherwise. Since your comment model has `belongs_to :user` without the optional key: `belongs_to :user, optional: true`, the creation of the comment will fail and will rollback, because it will create a database inconsistency (you'll have a comment without any user).

To fix this you have a couple of options:

1. Instead of directly creating the comments, build one (without saving it yet), and then assign the user_id:

```
   @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params) # This won't save to the database yet so it won't have any inconsistencies 
   @comment.user_id = current_user.id
   @comment.user.email = current_user.email #This line is unnecessary, the email is already assigned through the user relation
   @comment.save
```

2. A second option is to add the user_id to the comment_params, so that in the form you add a hidden field including `user_id = current_user.id`
3. Add the `optional: true` option in the `belongs_to` relation in the model, however I wouldn't recommend this.

If your comment creation is rolling back, you can inspect the error by running `@comment.errors`

Comment: Ok, I tried the first two options, but the error still persists. I didn't try the third option because you said you wouldn't recommend it. Any other ideas?

Comment: @JoshNismo could you go into the rails console and try getting the record? `Comment.last`, see if it has a related user_id. If it does, then there's a problem passing variables to the partial. Could you also add how you're rendering the partial?

Comment: Here is `Comment.last`: 
    ```irb(main):002:0> Comment.last
    Comment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" 
    ORDER BY "comments"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
    => #<Comment id: 13, comment_text: "Yes", created_at: "2019-07-05 
    17:38:40", updated_at: "2019-07-05 17:38:40", post_id: 2, user_id: 1>
    irb(main):003:0>```

I'm rerendering the partial here:

    ```<div class="comment-div">
        <%= render @post.comments %>
     </div>```

Comment: What do lines (2) and (3) print if you comment out line (4) where you're showing the e-mail? 
Could you try changing that rendering syntax for

`<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %><%= render partial: 'comment', locals: {comment: comment} %> <% end %>
`

Comment: Ok, so I had to modify your syntax a little to: ```<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
                <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: {comment: comment} %>
            <% end %>``` What I get with lines 2 and 3 are: 
```#<User:0x000000000d4c8170>```
and
```1```

Comment: I believe now that line 4 should work, try uncommenting it

Comment: Nope. I still keep getting: ```NoMethodError in Posts#show
Showing C:/Users/joshi/railsbridge/message_board/app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #4):
2
3
4
              
<p><%= comment.user %></p>
<p><%= comment.user_id %></p>
<p><%= comment.user.email %></p>```

Comment: That's very odd, because line (2) is saying that "User" is not nil, seems like the issue might be something different then

Comment: That's the weird thing, I know. I've been trying to figure out why in the world it's saying user is nil, yet 2 lines above that statement, user isn't nil...

Comment: One option to debug this more easily would be to install the gem `better_errors` and add a  <% raise %> statement just above the user that's giving you problems. You should be able to figure out what the problem is then

Comment: So i did find something strange. When I used `erb` to log the `current_user`, I'm getting it back twice: ```Hello

#<User:0x0000000009975e88>

1

#<User:0x000000000aff6a40>

#<User:0x000000000aff6a40>``` What's more interesting, perhaps, is the fact that the current_user and @comment.user are not the same, despite this line of code: ```@comment.user = current_user```